# Golang - Slices in nested structs

Tags: struct, go, slice

I have a deeply nested struct which contains two slices, as seen below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type bar struct {
    v1 []int
    v2 []int
}

type foo struct{ bar bar }
type tar struct{ foo foo }

func main() {
    f := &tar{foo: foo{bar: bar{v1: [2], v2: [3]}}}
    fmt.Printf("Hello, playground %s", f)
}
```

How do I initialize the two slices? Or how do I get this code working?

Here is the Golang Play for it: http://play.golang.org/p/zLutROI4YH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v1` and `v2` are slices. The way you initialize those is with `make([]int, YOUR_INITIAL_SIZE)` instead of `[2]` and `[3]`.

Comment: That's what I assumed. I was about to edit it and say if you want to initialize with known values, look at @Kavu's answer.

Comment: If you want to initialize empty, you're probably doing it wrong. Just leave them nil. The above case isn't empty, though, it's a bunch of zeros.  The literal example in the other answer is probably what the user wanted.

Comment: Good point, @Dustin. Because he had [2] and [3], I assumed that is what he wanted. Without more info about use case, can't really tell.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible with `[]int{1,2,3}` notation, example (solves your problem):

```
&tar{foo: foo{bar: bar{v1: []int{2}, v2: []int{2}}}}
```

P.S. I strongly advise you to read [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) and [FAQ section](http://golang.org/doc/faq).